# How to select only value if the month is finished

Tags: sql, date

I would like to create a variable who selects me only value when the month is finished.

For example, if I have a table 1 like that:

```
date           value

01/06/2021     100
02/06/2021     145
14/06/2021     652
14/04/2021     145
12/07/2021     111
08/07/2021     474
```

Then I want create a variable value_current from table 1 who returns me :

```
date_current   current_value
01/06/2021     100
02/06/2021     145
14/06/2021     652
14/04/2021     145
```

Because  July is not finished.

So when we will be  01/08,  my code will returns me these 2 value

Thanks !!

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using proc sql on sas

Comment: I tried with function extract

Comment: SQL Server has - EOMONTH function. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/. Could SAS have such function?